# Open a pdf file with appery.io when I click on a button

Tags: android, iphone

I am new to app development. I am trying to develop an app where I click on a button and a PDF file opens. I have uploaded the PDF file to my DB and it is in my Files Data of the Predefined collections. I originally thought I could set the button to open a link and point to the DB file, but I can't figure out how to do this. I did browse through the questions that talk about opening of PDF files, but I didn't find anything that I thought that could be helpful to me. I will greatly appreciate some help on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this all week, but I have finally got a working solution.  It's not the most elegant, but it works in my testing, and hopefully it will get you started.

First, map the response of your GET operation to a local storage variable (edoc1).  (You don't need to do this, but it seemed easier to me when I was trying to get it working.)
On the success event of the service, run the following JavaScript:

```
var globalEntry, b64d = localStorage.getItem('edoc1');

var fail = function(error) {
    alert(error);
};

var gotFileWriter = function(writer) {
    writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
        window.open(globalEntry.fullPath,"_system");
    };
    writer.write(atob(b64d));
};

var gotFileEntry = function(entry) {
    globalEntry = entry;
    entry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);                                
};    

var gotFS = function(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("my.pdf", { create: true }, gotFileEntry, fail);
};

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
```

This will save a file called my.pdf to local storage, then open it with your default system app.